# How to set a cross origin cookie? (CORS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

My cookies aren't being set. I've tried every possible variation of different headers middleware but I can't get it to work. I'm relatively new so if there are some key concepts that you think I don't understand please explain!

frontend part:

```
window.onload = function(){
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const url = "http://localhost:5001/";
  Http.open("GET",url,true);
  Http.withCredentials = true;
  Http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
  Http.send();
}

server side: 

app.get("/",stuff);

function stuff(req,res) {
    res.cookie("ss","ss");
    console.log("stuff");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:5500");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.send();
}
```

At first I had problem with CORS but now I've managed to get rid of that error, I still haven't been able to get it to save a cookie. I've managed to save a cookie from the domain where I make the request but not on this file where my HTML+CSS+JS is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set cross-origin cookies even though the origins are on the same host-name but diff rent ports. This presents a security flaw that would allow sites to set tracking cookies for other domains. That being said, there are a few possible workarounds:

## Setting cookies:

This can be achieved by responding to the http-request with JSON to tell the front-end to set the cookie.

## Getting cookies:

You can do this by passing the `document.cookie` variable as `FormData` to your backend, and parsing it there.